# How can I make the dropdown for this button ADA accessible?

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility

I have this button which when clicked opens a dropdown of checkboxes. I am able to use the 'tab' key to navigate to the button as well as hit the 'space' or 'enter' key to open the dropdown. But I am not able to navigate through the checkboxes of the dropdown by using the up and down arrow keys. This is the relevant code:

```
<button class = “setting-button" mat-button [matmenuTriggerfor] =“settings" <fa-icon [icon]-"settingsIcon"></fa-icon> </button>

<mat-menu #settings="matMenu" >
<div *ngFor="let id of arraycolumns">
<div *nglf=" ![‘Cashless', 'Borrower', 'options', 'isfavorite', 'Progress', 'Deal Name'].includes(id)" mat-menu-item >
 <mat-checkbox class="chkbx" #singleCheckbox [checked]= 'fieldcolumnsChecked.indexof(id) >= 0' (change)="checkcolumnsChanged(id)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
{{id}} 
</mat-checkbox>
</div> 
</div> 
</mat-menu>
```

And in the ts file I have this:

```
@ViewChildren("singleCheckbox") checkboxes!: QueryList<MatCheckbox>;
```

How can I enable navigation through the dropdown itself? Please help! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of Angular's HostListener to listen for keyboard events and manipulate the focus.

Add a tabIndex to the mat-checkbox to make it focusable and Implement HostListener in your component to listen for keydown events.

When arrow keys are pressed, change the focus of the checkboxes accordingly.

The HTML:

```
<mat-menu #settings="matMenu">
    <div *ngFor="let id of arraycolumns; let i = index">
        <div *ngIf="![‘Cashless', 'Borrower', 'options', 'isfavorite', 'Progress', 'Deal Name'].includes(id)" mat-menu-item>
            <mat-checkbox class="chkbx" #singleCheckbox [checked]='fieldcolumnsChecked.indexOf(id) >= 0' (change)="checkcolumnsChanged(id)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" [tabIndex]="i">
                {{id}} 
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</mat-menu>
```

typescript:

```
import { HostListener, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCheckbox } from '@angular/material/checkbox';

// ... (other imports)

export class YourComponent {

    @ViewChildren("singleCheckbox") checkboxes!: QueryList<MatCheckbox>;

    currentFocusIndex = 0;

    // ...

    @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (this.checkboxes && this.checkboxes.length) {
            if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.setFocus(true);
            } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.setFocus(false);
            }
        }
    }

    setFocus(goDown: boolean) {
        if (goDown && this.currentFocusIndex < this.checkboxes.length - 1) {
            this.currentFocusIndex++;
        } else if (!goDown && this.currentFocusIndex > 0) {
            this.currentFocusIndex--;
        }
        const checkboxArray = this.checkboxes.toArray();
        checkboxArray[this.currentFocusIndex].focus();
    }

    // ... (rest of your code)
}
```